How to search for a layer from ArcGIS Server within R using R-ArcGIS Bridge (arcgisbinding)
I want to search for all layers within my ArcGIS Server that have a pattern i.e. "Project one feature layer one", "Project one feature layer two".
I know I can get specific feature layers using this question and answer from Stack overflow but is there a way I don't have to provide a URL to get all the feature layers related to a specific project?
